# Salvar dado em LocalStorage e depois verificar se ele existe em outra pagina

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Boa tarde pessoa.
Estou precisando salvar um dado em LocalStorage e depois verificar se esse valor existe em outra página, tentei aqui mas não funcionou.

Primeiro defino o valor da "variavel" Prof_AMC

```
if($(myEmail == singleMail)){
            if(approved == true && categoria == 'PLF'){
                // Cria um item "Prof_AMC" com o e-mail do usuário
                window.localStorage.setItem('Prof_AMC', singleMail);
                window.location.href = document.referrer+'?sc=2'; // Parametro URL Politica PLF
            }
```

Depois em outra página eu tento verificar se ela existe e se o parametro SC é diferente de -1:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("sc")!=-1 && localStorage.getItem('Prof_AMC')){

}
```

Comment: vc deu um console.log nesse resultado localStorage.getItem('Prof_AMC') pra verificar o que ta vindo?

Comment: Digito localStorage.getItem('Prof_AMC') no console do chrome? Se for deu um erro Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: As duas páginas que acessam o LocalStorage são no mesmo domínio ou é um *redirect* externo?

Comment: tentou em outro navegador?

Comment: mesmo dominio, era um erro meu aqui por isso nao estava dando. Tentei agora e o resultado foi null, ou seja, não está passando a variavel para o localStorage

Comment: Também tentei no firefox e tbm deu null parece que não esta passando nada de uma pagina pra outra

Comment: tente a solução que eu postei ali, caso não funcione, va no seu código e logo após vc dar o setItem no localStorage, use o comando js console.log(localStorage) e veja se está salvando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionou quando fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
if($(myEmail == singleMail)){
            if(approved == true && categoria == 'PLF'){
                // Cria um item "Prof_AMC" com o e-mail do usuário
                window.localStorage.setItem('Prof_AMC', ""+singleMail+"");
                window.location.href = document.referrer+'?sc=2'; // Parametro URL Politica PLF
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu navegador está bloqueando o acesso ao localStorage.
Para resolver isso vá nas configurações de conteúdo do navegador e permita que sites terceiros salvem cookies e informações.
[veja aqui o caminho no chrome (em inglês)](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)

Comment: O problema é que não funciona nem no chrome, nem firefox, nem nenhum navegador. Então não creio que seja o navegador.

Comment: Acabei de descobrir que o problema não está no localStorage e  sim que ele não está permitindo eu salvar uma variavel nele. Se eu colocar apenas "teste" aí funciona.